# iOS - "Upload progress view" like the new facebook app

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I would like to have an "Upload-progress-view", in my app. Just like the one the new Facebook app has. The "Upload view" is only visible if an upload-progress is active.

The UIView shoud be visible on every UIViewController in my app.

Can I insert the "Upload-progress-view" in my AppDelegate?

I'am using AFNetworking.

/ Morten

Screenshot:

[image: Photo of upload bar]

As you can see it is a simpel UIView with a UIProgressView in it. My problem is how do I show this progress-view on every views (different UIViewControllers)?

Comment: Please post a screenshot, not all of us use Facebook :)

Answer (score 1):

This [progressBar](https://github.com/sprint84/WDUploadProgressView) can do the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using **ASIHttpRequest** to do the upload?

If yes take a look at [Cocoa File Upload with Progress Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4489107/1557663)

**EDITED:**

Ok, so use this

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api-base-url.com"];
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"avatar.jpg"], 0.5);
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST"   path:@"/upload" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData)     {
[formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"avatar" fileName:@"avatar.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
}];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request] autorelease];
[operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
NSLog(@"Sent %lld of %lld bytes", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
}];
[operation start];
```

from [GitHub AFNetworking - File Upload with Progress Callback](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

Comment: Cool... Thanks. But my problem is more how do I show a UIProgressView with data from the AFNetworking uploadProgress, on every screen (UIViewController) there is in my app. I want the user to see how far the upload progress is, no matter which ViewController is active. - But thanks for quick reply :)

Comment: Maybe if you define a UIView in your AppDelegate, call it in each view and append it has a subView of your ViewController it will work.